# Как вернуть фокус окну предыдущего приложения?

Tags: c#

По клику будет заполнятся буфер и возвращаться в предыдущее приложение, там из буфера должны заполняться строки (предполагаю переключение между теми строчками будет через Tab).
Возможно ли реализовать это ?

Comment: Вы хотите реализовать Windows поведение в части `Alt+Tab` прямой перебор окон, `Alt+Shift+Tab` - обратный перебор?

Comment: Alt+Tab, затем уже в приложении Tab + paste (возможно ли реализовать в коде?)

Comment: Конечно возможно, можете посмотреть как это реализовано в [keepass](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/code/HEAD/tree/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код:

```
SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}");
Clipboard.SetText(Regex.Match(fromTextBox.Text,@"^\w+ \w{1}").ToString());
SendKeys.Send("^v");
```

Работает под win7, для других не тестил.

Upd: SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}") не работает на вин8. Не могу разобраться как сделать. В манифесте поменял uiAccess="true", а что дальше не понятно.

Upd: Не знал что проще искать по процессам

Такой код правильнее:

```
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    Process[] handles = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
    SetForegroundWindow(handles[0].MainWindowHandle);
    Clipboard.SetText(text);
    SendKeys.SendWait("^v");
```

И он работает на вин 7 и 8